# Compare two directory and output in txt file with with differ file name in linux

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to get difference between two directory and writing output in txt file with only differ file names with these command in linux shell

```
diff -qr directory1/ directory2/ | sort > output.txt
```

It is giving me output in output.txt file like

```
Files directory1/1.txt and directory/1.txt differ
```

I need output only  `1.txt` as output

Is there any idea, i can get only differ filename as output in txt file.

thanks

thanks

Answer (score 1):

simply use:

```
diff -ur --brief dir1 dir2 | sed -e 's/Files dir1\///' -e 's/and .*//'
```